# php passing function argument value to select other string and give that a value

Tags: php, function, arguments

I've been racking my brains trying to think of a way round this. I have a header file which is called in every document on my site, and I need to dynamically select from each document which anchor is given a set value. as follows:

```
function headur($page) {echo'...
    <ul>
      <li><a'.$h.' href="/">Home</a>
      <li><a'.$s.' href="/services">Services</a>
      <li><a'.$p.' href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <li><a'.$a.' href="/about">About</a>
      <li><a'.$c.' href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </ul>...
  ;}
```

then in my document I call `headur($a);` and from that argument value - `$a` - use that as the selector to give the matching internal string a specific value -  `class="selected"` i.e. this particular function call would output the html like this:

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a>
      <li><a href="/services">Services</a>
      <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <li><a class="selected" href="/about">About</a>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </ul>
```

The whole point is that it's being dynamically selected from the document that calls the function, without me having to manually create a big old if statement to match everything up. i.e. `if ($page == $a) {$a = ' class="selected"';}` for each one, which is what I have been doing. I guess it's the php equivalent of doing `.addClass();` but on an external file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just store your class definitions in an array and search it by the index. Using numeric keys for the array would be simplest, but not very descriptive while reading back over your code. To use numeric keys just do something like this:

```
$pages = array("", "services", "portfolio", "about", "contact");
$where = array_search($a, $pages); // $a is the param passed to the function
$pages[$where] .= "\" class=\"selected\"";
```

I did your pages in order, so $h would be replaced by $pages[0], $s would be replaced by $pages[1] and so on. If you want me to write you some code so you can use textual keys in the array to make it easier, I can do that as well, but I personally think this works fine without the extra code.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for your reply, could you please clarify the argument that would be called in the function on each document? I added the bit of script you have written, and in the UL changed $h, $s etc to $pages[0], $pages[1] etc but in every which way I could think of and it simply didn't work. my current solution is 
      $z = ' class="selected"';
 if ($page == h) {$h = $z;} 
 elseif ($page == s) {$s = $z;} 
 elseif ($page == p) {$p = $z;} 
 elseif ($page == a) {$a = $z;}
 elseif ($page == c) {$c = $z;}
which works perfectly, but I was looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" href="/">Home</a>
    <li><a class="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/services' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" href="/services">Services</a>
    <li><a class="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/portfolio' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <li><a class="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/about' ? 'selected' : '' ?>"href="/about">About</a>
    <li><a class="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/contact' ? 'selected' : '' ?>" href="/contact">Contact</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately this didn't work out of the box, firstly I had to strip out the <?php declarations as this was already in a php function. Thanks for trying =)

Answer (score 0):

It is very typical to create an array, and iterate through the array:

```
$linkMenu = array(
    '/' => 'Home',
    '/services' => 'Services',
    '/portfolio' => 'Portfolio',
    '/about' => 'About',
    '/contact' => 'Contact',
);

function linkList($links, $page=null) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($links as $url=>$name) {
        $selected = ($url == $page) ? " class='selected' " : '';
        echo "<li><a $selected href='$url'>$name</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Now, you can create the link menu for the home page with:

```
linkList($linkMenu, '/');
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this returns an error `Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: When I copy-and-paste the code into a PHP file and run it as-is, I get the expected output.  Maybe you misspelled the `$linkMenu` variable name somewhere?

Comment: I copied and pasted it from what you submitted :/

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to load your template into a DOMDocument and set the Link as active which matches the current URL:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<ul><li><a href="/yourLink">Your Link</a></li></ul>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

foreach ($xpath->query(sprintf('//a[@href="%s"]', $uri)) as $current) {
    $current->setAttribute('class', 'selected');
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Code is not tested! But it should give you an idea... This way you can write your template-File without any PHP-Code at all in it...

Comment: Hi Markus, not exactly what I was looking for, I need to keep the setup purely PHP because of what I'm doing with it. Thanks for trying though =)